# After enabling earlyprintk the kernel prints twice the logs

Tags: linux, logging, linux-kernel, boot

I'm working on a project at the office where I have to enable the earlyprintk so that I can see the crashes at boot. So far so good, I've added `earlyprintk=mydriver ...` in the command line + some custom platform settings and I can see now the messages printed at boot.

...mydriver is a custom (the SoC) serial driver which is registered as the earlyprintk driver and does the driver setup at boot time.

However, the issue here is that I can see earlyprintk sending the logs, and when the log timestamp reaches 4,1 seconds, I see again the whole dmesg printed from timestamp 0.
So basically the normal console doesn't resume the printing where the earlyprink left off, but does a complete kernel buffer printing.

So far I couldn't find a way to solve this issue, any help much appreciated.

Thanks & Regards

mdaniel.

Comment: Try to use earlycon instead and register your driver to be able act as a such.

Comment: Thanks 0andriy. The platform I'm using is x86 based. Looking at the code it seems the x86 doesn't have the same support for earlycon as ARM has. On the other hand I don't have too much time to spend on this feature because I have several others on the list. The earlyprintk/earlycon was just the debugging support to help me with early boot crashes. Will try to check in new kernels maybe the earlycon is updated for x86 too. Regards.

Comment: X86 has support of early printk only for two first legacy ports.

Comment: This is a customized baseline where the driver for uart exists already in arch/x86/platform/.. and it's registered to earlyprintk framework. This is an embedded x86 platform, therefore the uart peripherals are not the standard ones. I just enabled the feature and customized it for my HW, where the linux shell is routed on another port (there are multiple uarts). As I said, earlyprintk works ok except for the double logging at boot. Searching for earlycon in kernel code I see something in ARM rather than x86. Perhaps I will look more into this when the time allows me. Tnx for the feedback.

Comment: I hope you are going to read some documentation regarding `earlycon`, I would like just to share main idea of it. Instead of some hackish way (`earlyprintk`) this one is trying to enable real serial driver to support output. It's quite independent to the architecture it runs on. The ARM boards are main users for now. But nothing prevents to do this on x86.